# What does Addie Brik's song "Wattsland" refer to?

Tags: alternative-rock

There's this weirdly captivating song by Addie Brik, called "Wattsland" (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQnin6Q7Kak)). To provide a little bit of context, Addie Brik is a singer from Georgia, one-time girlfriend of RHCP's Hillel Slovak. In the 1980s she hung out in LA with the guys who later went on to form RHCP. I was a bit puzzled about the meaning of the song's title, but then realized that Watts is a neighborhood in southern LA (known for high gang activity and a wave of racial riots in the 60s). I'm not completely sure this is the right track so if anybody knows for sure, I'd appreciate an explanation.